# phpList is not showing Initialize Database Option

Tags: mysql, centos-6

I just installed `phpList` on server. Also created `mysql` database. Now, I am opening it through `ip-address/phplist/admin`, It is showing just header. I can't see any option to `Initialize Database`. Soo, I am not able to go ahead.
Please help me.
Check Screen Shot :

[image: phpList]

Comment: `access.log`? `error.log`? Error display `on`?

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky, It is showing 500 Internal Server Error when i checked Console of Brower. What should i check now ?

Comment: That's not enough. Clean the log files, turn on error reporting and reload the page.

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky, where i can find log file ?

Comment: Please use google